# How to get index Value of Selected Dojox.mobile.listItem?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, dojox.mobile

I am developing a worklight project using DOJO toolkit.Since i am a newbie in Worklight and Dojo i just created a list and trying to get get the index of clicked list,so that i can show corresponding description/action in the next view.
i tried passing index value in listItem "onClick " function,but after passing index parameter i cant move to anothe view.

HTML File

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0"
        data-dojo-props="selected:false,scrollDir:'v'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
            data-dojo-props="label:'View0'" ></div>
        <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" id="dataList">

        </ul>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
            data-dojo-props="fixed:'bottom'"></div>
    </div>
```

JS File

```
function abcd()
    {
    ..
    ...
    ...
     var dlist = dijit.registry.byId("view0");
    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
    var lstId = "list" + i;
    var list = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({label: labl,rightIcon:"mblDomButtonBlueCircleArrow",transition:"slide",id:lstId,onClick:dispData(lstId),moveTo:"#"});
}
                    dlist.addChild(list);


    }

    function dispData(index)
    {
        //debugger;
        alert(index);
        dijit.registry.byId("view0").performTransition("**someview***", 1, "slide");
    }
```

How to get the index value of selected list in dojo.Is there any other method to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the loop index as a closure variable for a click handler being defined in the loop ... that isn't going to work.  (see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for example)

I find it easier to just add the id to the ListItem and then use the event to find the item in a single click handler:

```
        function listItemHandler(event) {
            // Look up the clicked ListItem and get its id 
            var id = dijit.registry
                    .getEnclosingWidget(event.currentTarget).id;

            alert(id);
        }

        var dlist = dijit.registry.byId("dataList");
        for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            var lstId = "list" + i;
            var list = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
                label : "label" + lstId,
                rightIcon : "mblDomButtonBlueCircleArrow",
                transition : "slide",
                id : lstId,
                moveTo : "#"
            });
            dlist.addChild(list);
        }
        dojo.query("#dataList .mblListItem").on("click", listItemHandler);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.what is .mblListItem in dojo.query("#dataList .mblListItem").on("click", listItemHandler);

Comment: mblListItem is is a class that the dojo parser adds to each list item element.

Answer (score 0):

Build the row such:

```
..'label': 'xx', 'moveTo':'#', 'onClick':function(){  yourFunction('id_of_item')}   ..
```

Use this in function for move to another view

```
var w = dijit.byId('currentView');
w.performTransition('newView',1,"slide",null); //or #newView
```

it works for me. The alert is displayed? It enter in function?

Comment: appreciate for replying back.My problem is how to get the selected listItem index so that i can display data in another view based on the selected one..

Comment: i edited my JS file.Here i am trying to create 3 listItem inside a for loop.I am also dynamically creating id for each listitem.When i execute the code and click any of the list Item i am getting "list3" alert.Alert is showing only the last lstId value that is list3.